# Do the lyrics a the beginning of Rock of Ages by Def Leppard mean anything?

Tags: lyrics, meaning, def-leppard

At the beginning of the song *Rock of Ages*, there are four words muttered that sound like gibberish that are:

> Gunter, glieben, glauchen, globen

Do these words actually mean anything?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's something from the [Def Leppard FAQ](http://defleppard.snaggledworks.com/dlfaq.txt):

> These four words that you hear at the start of "Rock of Ages", mean
>   nothing, though the band sometimes jokingly claims it means "running
>   through the forest silently". It's actually just German sounding
>   gibberish, said by producer Mutt Lange during one of the later takes
>   of the song. Lange was a perfectionist and would often do dozens &
>   dozens of takes, and after repeatedly beginning so many with the
>   standard count, "One, two, three, four" he simply started saying
>   nonsense words instead, the band liking this one so much that they
>   included it on the album.

So it's a load of nonsense that became an in-joke with the band.